# install module jupyter notebook

Tags: gradient, super

I have completed
from ultralytics import NAS
model = NAS('yolo_nas_s.pt')

returns an error:No module named 'super_gradients'

How to install super_gradients in jupyter notebook for YOLO-NAS
what you need to do to make YOLO-NAS work correctly. Do I need additional modules

Comment: Did you run in your notebook `%pip install super-gradients`, like stated [here](https://github.com/Deci-AI/super-gradients#quick-installation) and [here](https://docs.deci.ai/super-gradients/#quick-installation)? (Use `!pip install super-gradients` if actually in GoogleColab and not true, modern Jupyter.) Then after that completes, restart the kernel and try again.

Comment: in GoogleColab it turned out, but it didn't work out in  jupyter notebook

Comment: I'm not following. So that solved it for now? But not in vanilla Jupyter?